# Stopping function in jupyter notebook (python 3) after set amount of time

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook, timer, user-input

If I have a function waiting for specific input that may never come, I want it to stop after set amount of time and move on.

I can do this in python 3 using timedinput module, signal module, or parallel process loops but when I try to run this in jupyter notebook, it never ceases running.

I’m using a Mac and chrome browser

I want something that works on jupyter notebook and python 3, else I’ve solved problem already

Code that works in jupyter notebook specifically, can just be simple function that asks for input and if doesn’t get input after x amount of times uses standard value.

Comment: What’s your current code? Please share what you have tried so far!